# ¿Como consigo el contenido de href de un video con seleniun dentro de un iframe?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

tengo un problema al querer conseguir el contenido de un href que tiene un video. Llegue a ingresar a la pagina y hacer click en el video, el href aparece en la pagina una vez que hago click en el video, hasta hacer click en el video llego, pero despues no puedo conseguir llegar hasta el href.

Este es el codigo de la pagina

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo es mas largo y el href esta dentro de un iframe pero sinceramente no se como copiar el text del html por eso mande la imagen.. quiero conseguir el contenido del href como muestra la iagen, pero no llego hasta ahi. Ese contenido aparece cuando le doy click al video. A continuacion dejo mi codigo

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time, re, requests

algo = "Player YouTube"
driver.get("https://www.supertelevisionhd.net/dragon-ball-z-en-vivo/")
time.sleep(1)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='post-100']/div/center/iframe"))
time.sleep(1)
click1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="{}"]'.format(algo))
time.sleep(5)
click1.click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '/html/body/iframe')))
time.sleep(5)
enlace = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_selected((By.CLASS_NAME,'html5-vpl_title_l vpl-antialiased')))
print(enlace)
```

Este es el error que recibo

```
> File "C:\Users\Nico\Desktop\pruebas driver.py", line 36, in <module>
> enlace = WebDriverWait(driver,
> 10).until(EC.element_to_be_selected((By.CLASS_NAME,'html5-vpl_title_l
> vpl-antialiased'))) File
> "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py",
> line 71, in until value = method(self._driver) File
> "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py",
> line 329, in call return self.element.is_selected() AttributeError:
> 'tuple' object has no attribute 'is_selected'
```

Agredeceria cualquier ayuda. Repito, lo que quiero obtener es el cotenido de href, osea lo que dice http://ok.ru....

Gracias

Comment: línea del error?

Comment: return self.element.is_selected()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'is_selected'

Comment: No veo esa línea en el código :/

Comment: lo que te puse arriba, es el error que recibo..

Comment: Entiendo perfectamente que sea el error, pero en que línea se produce?

Comment: Alguien me puede dar una mano?

Comment: Ya sé que es lo que pasa, hay otro html dentro del html. Lo que debes hacer es buscar el primer iframe y luego dentro del mismo iframe, buscar el otro mainframe que está en el segundo html. `driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//frame[@name='mainFrame']"))` (lo tienes que poner dos veces según la secuencia). Deja te lo comento

Comment: Una duda, ¿solo quieres que se te imprima en la consola la url que solicitas o quieres que se abra la url en una nueva ventana?

Comment: @ulises solo quiero obtener la url que esta dentro del href